# Can "tee" command in linux print both the input and the output of a C program?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I have a simple C program where the it will ask to take an integer from the user, and then it will print that integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {   
    int number;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");  
    scanf("%d", &number);
    printf("You entered: %d", number);  
    return 0;}
```

When I use this command:

```
gcc program.c -o test
./test | tee text.txt
```

The program running on terminal does not print the enter integer line but instead, waits for an input and when I provide that input, it prints it and also into the text.txt folder. I want to run the program as it is and store everything running on terminal into the text.txt folder including both the input and the output. Any possible way to do that?

Comment: This has nothing in particular to do with C.  The same considerations would apply to a program written in any language.

Comment: Is there any other command that will do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tee` command works with *one* input, but you want to capture two.  With some care, you could use two separate `tee` commands two copy both the input and the output to the same file, but you would be better off with a utility designed for your purpose, such as [script](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html).

Comment: How about piping several file descriptors to stdout?

Answer (score 0):

For Debian based Linuxes, run `apt install devscripts`, and then try the  [**`annotate-output`**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/annotate-output) util.  For example, run `cat` using a process substitution and a file that's not there at all:

```
annotate-output cat <(echo hello) /bin/nosuchfile
```

...which shows what otherwise would be input, output, and standard error output, all sent to standard output which could then be piped to a file:

```
13:01:03 I: Started cat /dev/fd/63 /bin/nosuchfile
13:01:03 O: hello
13:01:03 E: cat: /bin/nosuchfile: No such file or directory
13:01:03 I: Finished with exitcode 1
```